# Reinstalled windows 7 now can't get access to dual boot

Tags: windows-7, linux, grub, operating-systems

I had a dual boot setup with a Debian based distro (crunchbang) as primary and win 7 also installed. Recently I reinstalled win 7 on it's existing partition but now the boot loader is gone and win 7 starts automatically.

How do I get the boot loader back to select my is at boot? Think it was grub running previously. I don't want to reinstall crunchbang if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

The general steps in these cases are:

1. Boot from a live CD
2. Mount your linux partitions
3. Bind mount /dev /proc /sys /dev/pts
4. Chroot in the mounted system
5. Re-install GRUB

From crunchbang forum:
http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=15351